# Laravel url call usein javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This is my Laravel route

```php
Route::get('upload-question/{sugg_id}/upload/{question_id}', ['uses' => 'QustionUploadController@store', 'role'=>['admin'], 'as' => 'upload.question.store']);
```

I'm using the script bellow in this page(add.blade.php) to cal this route

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','.add-question',function(){
        var id =  $(this).attr('data-id');
        let url = "{{ url('admin/upload-question/'.$id.'/upload') }}/"+id;
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
            alertify.success(data.message);
        }.bind(this));
    })

</script>
```

Here, I'm sending two variable. One is `$id`, it is available in this page(add.blade.php), which I sent  using compact method, another one is 'id', getting from `data-id` attribute, from this button bellow,

```html
<button type="button" id="btn{{$question->id}}" data-id="{{$question->id}}" class="add-question btn green-haze btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm"> Add </button>
```

Along with this `id` variable if I want to send one more variable. 
Say, `<input type="number" value="{{$medicine->quantity}}">`, I want the value of `$medicine->quantity` to be sent

So how can I obtain it and bind this value with 'url' variable of this JavaScript.

I have a very poor knowledge on JavaScirpt, so need the help in detail.

Answer (score 0):

In html, you can add data attributes like you did with the id. So for the quantity, I'd simply add it in an attribute called 'data-quantity' on the same button element. Like this:

`<a href="" data-id="{{$question->id}}" data-quantity="{{$medicine->quantity}}" class="add-question btn green-haze btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm"></a>`

You can retrieve these values in javascript with jQuery like this:

```
let elementData = $(<Button Element>).data();
elementData.id // should equal $question->id
elementData.quantity // should equal $medicine->quantity
```

Comment: Ok. Now I can get the value of other variable. But how to send it with this,         let url = "{{ url('admin/upload-question/'.$id.'/upload') }}/"+id